# Check if an element doesn't exist and append it

Tags: jquery

I want select all items that haven't an IMG tag and append it. I can do that:

How can i do that?

```
  <div class="test">
     <div class="someDummydiv"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="test">
     <div class="someDummydiv"></div>
     <img src="try.gif" />
  </div>
  <div class="test">
     <div class="someDummydiv"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="test">
    <div class="someDummydiv"></div> 
    <img src="try.gif" />
  </div>
  <div class="test">
     <div class="someDummydiv"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="test">
     <div class="someDummydiv"></div>
     <img src="try.gif" />
 </div>
```

Result -->

```
  <div class="test">
     <div class="someDummydiv"></div>
     <img src="try.gif" />
  </div>
  <div class="test">
     <div class="someDummydiv"></div>
     <img src="try.gif" />
  </div>
  <div class="test">
     <div class="someDummydiv"></div>
     <img src="try.gif" />
  </div>
  <div class="test">
     <div class="someDummydiv"></div>
     <img src="try.gif" />
  </div>
  <div class="test">
     <div class="someDummydiv"></div>
     <img src="try.gif" />
  </div>
  <div class="test">
     <div class="someDummydiv"></div>
     <img src="try.gif" />
  </div>
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 9):

You can use a selector that checks for existence using [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/), and append to those, like this:

```
$('.test:not(:has(img))').append('<img src="try.gif" />');
```

Just replace the selector inside the `:not(:has(selector))` to look for what you want to [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

Comment: That's really clean.  My approach should work as well, and would allow extra processing for elements that don't have images as well, but a one liner is always nice.  :)

Answer (score 1):

This should come close:

```
$('div.test').each(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.children('img').size() == 0) {
    $this.append('<img src=try.gif>');
  }
});
```